# Disable ToolStripMenuItem according to User Role in C#

Tags: c#

I'm having some problems to disable some ToolStripMenuItems according to Logged User Role.

This is my recursive method to get all buttons in Form...

```
public IEnumerable<Button> Buttons
    {
        get
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
            foreach (Control ctrl in Form.ActiveForm.Controls)
            {
                Button btn = ctrl as Button;
                if (btn != null)
                {
                    buttons.Add(btn);
                }
            }
            return buttons;
        }
    }
```

This is the method to check if User has permissions and disable button:

```
public static void ActiveButtons(string user, MenuStrip menu)
    {
        if (CanNavigate(user))
        {
            foreach(Control c in Form.ActiveForm.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(MenuStrip))
                {
                    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menu.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.Name == "novoToolStripMenuItem")
                        {
                            item.Visible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, call the function from Load event of the Form:

```
Extensions.UserInfo.ActiveButtons(Extensions.UserInfo.CurrentLoggedUser, menuStrip);
```

But, when the Form is Loaded with a User which has no Access to Navigate, the MenuStrip Item is still avaiable to click.

Can anyone please help me getting this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me that there is a fault in your `CanNavigate` function. If that returns true, the button will be visible, otherwise it will not be visible. Also, the parameter `user` is not used in your `ActiveButtons` function.

Comment: You're right! I've changed my code. But I think I've a problem because the Button is not a button by a ToolStripMenuItem and I need to disable one of those Items in MenuStrip.

Comment: You're right, I missed the part about the MenuStrip. Your current collection only holds `Button`s and not all controls so any non-`Button` controls will not be hidden. I think you should loop through all of the controls, check their type and name and then show/hide them accordingly

Comment: Your Buttons-function does not take into account that controls have hierarchy, if the form has a panel for example, the panel will have Controls-property which in turn can have multiple child-controls. So the function should be recursive to go through all the controls.

Comment: So, I've changed my CanNavigate method to check for MenuStrip controls but still button is active! Thus, the IEnumerable<Button> method is useless now. @Esko, the MenuStrip doesn't have a panel behind. Can you help figure this out?

Comment: You are not using the Buttons-function for anything anymore? Have you debugged the code which you have now and see why the visible = false is never accessed?

Comment: Forms.ActiveForm.Controls has an System.NullReferenceException. The menu.Items can see the 2 Menu's I have (File and Operations) but I think it cannot see the child items. The one I'm trying to disable is inside File Menu.